# Delphi how to implement baseclass event?

Tags: delphi, inheritance, keypress

I have an abstract Delphi XE form that acts as base class for a family of forms used in my application. I am trying to figure out the best way to make a help function (on F1 keypress) that opens a wiki-page for the active form.

I'd very much like this function to be implemented at base-class level and to call when the user presses F1 but I need some advice on how to do this in a smart way. Currently I just put a KeyDown-event on the base form but this gets overwritten if the subform receives its own KeyDown, at which point I have to manually call the baseKeyDown. Obviously, this is not optimal.. Is there a way to ensure I catch the F1 keypress at baseclass level, random overloads nonwithstanding?

I am running Delphi XE on Windows 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should override `KeyDown` method in your base form class.

```
type
  TBaseForm = class(TForm)
  protected
    procedure KeyDown(var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState); override;
  end;

procedure TBaseForm.KeyDown(var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  // do your processing here
  // ...
  inherited; // call inherited method that will call OnKeyDown if assigned
end;
```

This is default implementation of KewDown method that calls `OnKeyDown` events

```
procedure TWinControl.KeyDown(var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if Assigned(FOnKeyDown) then FOnKeyDown(Self, Key, Shift);
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

The straight answer to your question is that a library writer should not assign to event handlers. That's because doing so makes it hard for library consumers to also consume those events. And when you are writing a base class, you are taking the role of the library author.

So, instead of implementing the handler in the `OnKeyDown` event, override the `KeyDown` method.

```
type
  TBaseForm = class(TForm)
  protected
    procedure KeyDown(var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState); override;
  end;
....
procedure TBaseForm.KeyDown(var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  inherited; // this will fire the OnKeyDown event
  // your processing for F1 goes here
end;
```

---

However, I wonder if you would not be better off using the built in help system. Personally I'd add an `OnHelp` event for the `Application` object and place the centralised logic there.

Comment: I agree with David. You should rather use built in help system instead.

Comment: Yep. Couldn't get the subforms to trigger onHelp which was the reason I went to KeyDown in the first place.. I found out what was wrong and so I'm back on the application.onHelp road.. Sorry for posting xy problems :( The answers might be useful to someone with a similar problem so I'll leave the question up